# Inserting an array in mongodb using mongoose in a schema where other fields are already added from user registration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am creating an application for online course.
I have created a schema for user registration. In the schema, I also want to add the name of courses a user in enrolled. Course Name being an array. 
User registration is successful. after that I have created a route for /dashboard, where the user sends the POST request to add the course name. That course should be added in the same registration schema field for course Enrolled. However When I save a new object of registration schema, it creates a new document field courseEnrolled field. I want this POST request value to be added in the user's document field of courseEnrolled as an array.

Here is how I have defined my registration schema. Its name in account.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var courseSchema = new Schema({ courseName : String });

var Account = new Schema({

username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
password: String,
email: String,
firstName: String,
lastName: String,
courseEnrolled: [{courseName : String}]
});

Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

Here is my passport registration . register.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/account');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var course = require('../models/courseEnrollment');

module.exports = function(passport){

passport.use('register', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {

        findOrCreateUser = function(){
            // find a user in Mongo with provided username
            User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err){
                    console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
                    return done(err);
                }
                // already exists
                if (user) {
                    console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('message','User Already Exists'));
                } else {
                    // if there is no user with that email
                    // create the user
                    var newUser = new User();
                    var newCourse = new course();

                    // set the user's local credentials
                    newUser.username = username;
                    newUser.password = createHash(password);
                    newUser.email = req.body.email;
                    newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;
                    newUser.lastName = req.body.lastName;
                    newUser.courseEnrolled = req.body.courseEnrolled;

                    // save the user
                    newUser.save(function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
                            throw err;
                        }
                        console.log('User Registration succesful');
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });

                }
            });
        };
        // Delay the execution of findOrCreateUser and execute the method
        // in the next tick of the event loop
        process.nextTick(findOrCreateUser);
    })
);

// Generates hash using bCrypt
var createHash = function(password){
    return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
}

}
```

I can register a user successfully. After that I have a route for /dashboard, where I handle the POST request to add a course. 
Here is the snippet of my /dashboard handling POST request.

```
var User = require('../models/account');
/* POST dashboard Page */

router.post('/dashboard', isAuthenticated, function (req, res) {

sess = req.session.passport.user;
console.log('session value is: ' + sess);
var newUser = new User();
console.log('newUser id is: ' + newUser._id);
var currentUser = req.user._id;
console.log('current User id is: ' + currentUser);
var myUser = req.user;
console.log('myUsers value is: ' + myUser);
var myUserCourse = req.user.courseEnrolled;

if (sess == currentUser) {

  //var newCourse = new course();
  console.log('request received: ' + req.body.courseEnrolled);
  req.user.courseEnrolled = req.body.courseEnrolled;

  newUser.save(function (err, data) {
    if(error)
      throw error;
    else {
      console.log('course Updated');
    }
  });
 res.render('home', {user: req.user});


}
});
```

This newUser.save() function creates a new document in the mongodb and store the courseEnrolled. I want to store the value of req.body.courseEnrolled in the same document field where other user value is defined.

This is getting stored in collection:- 'accounts' for the user

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57f95afd9c78b91c69334f0d"),
"lastName" : "Nehra",
"firstName" : "Ashish",
"email" : "ashish.nehra@stanford.edu",
"password" : "$2a$10$YzLvbQTHFtq5l0ooP0njOux94Rp.pm.Pkb/TugBnCSTUJNhBBonLG",
"username" : "ashish",
"courseEnrolled" : [
    "about to change something now"
],
"__v" : 1
}
```

And there is a new document being created like this in the same collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5803fc4342ca1d3167102300"),
"courseEnrolled" : [ ],
"__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logical because first you do a it on various user objects (req.user / new user):

```
**var newUser = new User();
```

This will create a new User object, and then:

```
newUser.save(function (err, data) {
```

This will save the newly created user into a new document. If you want to use the .save, rewrite it to (reused your own code):

```
User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, function(err, user) {
      // In case of any error, return using the done method
      if (err){
          console.log('Error in SignUp: '+err);
          return done(err);
      }

      user.courseEnrolled = req.body.courseEnrolled;

      user.save(function (err, data) {
    if(err)
      throw err;
    else {
      console.log('course Updated');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I got reference error.

Comment: events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at /home/mobileedx/WebstormProjects/passportAuthentication/routes/index.js:228:19
    at /home/mobileedx/WebstormProjects/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3340:16
    at /home/mobileedx/WebstormProjects/passportAuthentication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1949:15
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: Yes i saw it was because of a copy/paste issue.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However I want to add the courseEnrolled in an array. If you look at the schema then you will see that its an array. Here if I add the new course, it replaces the previous one. I want to make sure that the new course is added in the array, along with previous courses.

Comment: Then you have to push the new course to the array. This can be done on the courseEnrolled in your code [javascript push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) of with the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.